# Setting up react-create-app with ES

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am actually using I am using https://github.com/ayroblu/ssr-create-react-app-v2 which is based off react-create-app

Trying to use `import` and `async/await` in my server side code but unable to run build.

My build script uses `"build": "react-scripts build",`. Can I configure that script or do I need to replace the whole build script with something custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was trying to call code from `./server` inside `./src` which was causing issues with the build.

Also discovered running `npm run eject` gives me more access to the build / start scripts